# Ask question usability

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, ios-app

I'm new to the app and am not clear how I'm navigating between sites. Some issues:

1. The Ask question page should have the site name in the header, so I don't get flamed for asking on the wrong site.
2. On an iPad, I'm not used to having buttons above the home row of the keyboard.  My thumbs regularly hit the buttons by accident.  Can they be moved farther away, or elsewhere.  I've never see this before.
3. The tags field is mandatory,  but hidden by my virtual keyboard.

Comment: +1 I've just noticed something related.  I check my mailbox (where messages have a small icon to indicate the site they come from) and follow a link but once I'm there, or if I follow any links to another SE site, there seems to be no easy way to know which site I am on.

Comment: As a workaround, if the markdown bar buttons bother you, you can hide them by tapping the leftmost double-arrow button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I have added the site name in the navigation bar (header) – it was an empty space anyway, and this is a good use for it. This change will appear in **version  1.1.0.131**

   > [image]
2. Since these markdown buttons are bothering you, they can be hidden by tapping on the triple arrow button in the leftmost part of the toolbar:

   > [image]
3. Though the tags field is often scrolled under the keyboard, you can see it again by scrolling to the bottom of your question/answer content. This isn't necessarily an ideal user experience – could you submit a separate question that focuses on that issue?

Comment: Could someone have fixed this?   I just upgraded to .130 and noticed that the markdown buttons were gone and the tags box was visible.

Comment: Ignore that last comment.  The markdown buttons showed up when I moved to the body.